# index() of last occurrence in list in python

Tags: python, indexing

In my for loop, I got this code:

```
start = listData.index(datum) + 1
```

and listData is:

```
listData = ['H66', 'B35', 'L21', 'B35', 'H66', 'J02', 'J04', 'L21', 'J20']
```

what I want is start = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9

but I got start = 1,2,3,2,1,6,7,3 (because index() return the index of the first occurrence? I guess?)

Is there any way to index last occurrence ?

Comment: with the last occurrence, you would have `5, 4, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`...

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP wants exactly. He/She wants to find an occurrence of an element and then if needs to find again then it should prompt for the second occurrence.

Comment: If I'm correct, then the OP should rephrase the question for the post to be considered for reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
start = len(listData) - listData[::-1].index(datum)
```

(ie. the last index is the first index from the reversed list)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
>>> listData = ['H66', 'B35', 'L21', 'B35', 'H66', 'J02', 'J04', 'L21', 'J20']
>>> def return_last(x):
...     return len(listData)-listData[::-1].index(x)-1
... 
>>> return_last("L21")
7
>>> return_last("H66")
4
```